# Changing the root password

Tags: linux, root

What are the implications of changing the root password? Is there anything that will be affected? I'm using a private shared SSH key - I assume I do not need to change this as it is not tied to the root account password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't say there are no implications on your system, as I have no idea what strange things your might have done, but I've never had *any* on mine. After all, it's just a password.

Of course, it might be easy to create systems where the root password is stored somewhere for some purpose, but I would consider this bad design to begin with.

And you are right, SSH keys don't need to be touched.

Comment: Will changing the root password affect the mailing server or database server?

Comment: It should not. I would say that if it does, you did something wrong, but I don't know your environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't afford to risk it, then consider restoring your server from a backup, or if it's a virtual machine make a clone of it, and test resetting the password.

Answer (score 0):

Not many aside from choosing a weak password.

If your system encrypts users home directories it is possible you could be in for a bad time if you then forget the new password.

Standard practice is to not give root access to services like ssh, and instead have users sudo for privilege, this means you can track who logged in with the escalated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If you log in as root by using an ssh key, then you don't need the password. I have multiple servers on which I have changed the root password to be a random string of characters which is not recorded anywhere.

Keys that are already authenticated through `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` will keep working after the root password has been changed. And if you always authenticate using a key, there is no need to know the password.

A couple of things to keep in mind:

- Administrating the server locally rather than across the network becomes more troublesome if you don't know the root password, and may require you to reboot the server.
- A random password known to nobody still has to be strong enough to not be possible to brute force.
- You can configure the system such that there is no valid password at all. But if you do that pay close attention to the difference between:

  - permitting login without password
  - asking for a password but never accepting any
  - suspending the account